# Passing parameter into jQuery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, callback, scope

How can I get each click callback to show i = 1, 2, 3, 4 when clicking on each div box, respectively?  jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/91v7b12c/2/
The way it is now, each click shows a '4', the last value for i.  Thanks.

```
div {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
<div id='3'></div>
<div id='4'></div>
<label></label>


var n = 4
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    $('#' + i)
    .click (function (){cb (i)})

} // end for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)

function cb (j) {
    $('label').text(j)
}
```

Comment: Let jQuery do the looping: `$('div').click(function() { cb(this.id); });`

Comment: @adeneo.  I'm not looking to create an array of functions, so I don't see how the link you provided answers my question.

Comment: @FelixKling I need a more general solution.  The id coincidentally matches the variable i that I passed in.  I'm not actually looking for the id of the clicked box.  What if I had:  var var1 = i*2 for example, and wanted the output on each clicked div to show: 2,4,6,8?

Comment: `$('div').forEach(function(index) { $(this).click(function() { cb(index * 2); }); });` ?

Comment: *"I'm not looking to create an array of functions"* But you are creating functions inside a loop and thus have the same problem.

Comment: How do I solve this without using jquery's foreach?  I'm not interested in restructuring that part of the code.  This is a very simple example of a larger problem I have.

Comment: A general solution is presented in the linked question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69850/discussion-between-tgoneil-and-felix-kling).

Comment: The solution is in the answer in the link, either you use `each` which will create a new scope in the callback function, or you do something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/91v7b12c/3/**

Comment: Ok, thank you for providing that, but I like this solution better:  
    .click ({i: i}, function (event){cb (event.data.i)})

event.data makes it a cleaner solution